# Infinity animation

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I'm creating a loader for the website. I'm implementing an infinite animation in case the initial animation is not sufficient and the data doesn't load in time. The first animation works fine, but after the first one, all subsequent ones start to lag. The animations begin to play out of order as intended and overlap each other.

Code:

```css
.loader {
    position: relative;
    margin: 100px 0 0 0;
    width: fit-content;
}

.loader svg {
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    transform: scale(0.7);
    animation: scaleAnimation 3s 2s forwards infinite;
}

.loader svg path {
    stroke-dashoffset: 2600;
    stroke-dasharray: 2600;
    animation: drawAnimation 2s forwards infinite;
}

.loader svg g {
    fill-opacity: 0;
    animation: fillAnimation 2s 2s forwards infinite;
}

@keyframes drawAnimation {
    to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        stroke-dasharray: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes fillAnimation {
    to {
        fill-opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes scaleAnimation {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0.7);
    }
    25% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    50% {
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}

.loader-pulse {
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(100% - 290px);
    left: calc(100% - 280px);
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #0e6655;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    animation: pulseAnimation 2s 2s forwards infinite;
}

@keyframes pulseAnimation {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0);
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
    50% {
        transform: scale(1);
        opacity: 0.2;
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(2);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="loader">
        <div class="loader-pulse"></div>
        <svg width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 800 800"
             xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <g stroke="#000" fill="#000" fillRule="nonzero">
                <path
                        d="M181.744 163.18C184.283 154.007 194.221 149.066 203.068 152.578L205.406 153.507C213.706 156.802 217.701 166.253 214.283 174.503L197.5 215L133.5 431L65.9184 636.561C63.3952 644.235 55.5466 648.825 47.6207 647.261L41.7807 646.108C32.1656 644.21 26.5008 634.193 29.8305 624.975L112 397.5L153 267L181.744 163.18Z"
                />
                <path
                        d="M251.674 146.311C245.696 137.958 233.507 137.322 226.692 145.007L225.104 146.798C220.088 152.454 219.715 160.848 224.21 166.927L251.937 204.425C252.71 205.471 253.353 206.608 253.852 207.81L289.535 293.878C289.845 294.625 290.097 295.394 290.29 296.179L315 396.5L353.016 591.621C354.863 601.098 364.62 606.793 373.781 603.74L374.852 603.383C382.399 600.867 386.951 593.19 385.538 585.361L371.122 505.5L344 380L303.142 241.5L277.168 182.516C276.724 181.508 276.177 180.549 275.536 179.653L251.674 146.311Z"
                />
                <path
                        d="M11.1407 416.041C2.31048 417.956 -3.18362 426.798 -0.989713 435.563L-0.337561 438.168C1.78945 446.666 10.3544 451.874 18.8776 449.851L62.5 439.5L140.5 419.541L230 404.5L318.5 391.5L363 384L386.299 378.107C395.675 375.735 400.82 365.653 397.238 356.67L395.69 352.787C391.804 343.04 379.745 339.609 371.31 345.851L365.705 349.999C363.921 351.318 361.882 352.253 359.718 352.743L328.957 359.704L218 376.5L95.5 398.5L39 410L11.1407 416.041Z"
                />
                <path
                        d="M522.944 366.006C514.679 369.045 510.423 378.191 513.42 386.47L513.775 387.448C516.486 394.937 524.292 399.291 532.088 397.664L556.926 392.479L613 373.5L675.5 353L737.359 335.658L765.5 331.838L779.302 331.838C788.174 331.838 794.806 323.686 793 315V315L791.921 311.402C789.891 304.635 783.661 300 776.596 300L770.241 300C769.415 300 768.59 300.064 767.774 300.191L745.78 303.624L668.5 326L580.5 345.5L542 359L522.944 366.006Z"
                />
                <path
                        d="M710.55 121.621C710.184 120.543 709.705 119.508 709.119 118.532L707 115L704.331 111.33C703.448 110.116 702.399 109.032 701.214 108.111L699.648 106.893C698.884 106.299 698.068 105.775 697.21 105.329L694.33 103.83C693.27 103.279 692.151 102.847 690.994 102.545L687 101.5L681.332 100.366C680.115 100.123 678.874 100.022 677.633 100.065L665.234 100.5L647.734 102L631.234 105.5L618.734 109L606.734 113.5L592.734 119.5L578.234 126.5L553.734 141.5L541.734 150.5L530.234 159.5L508.234 179.5L487.234 201L477.234 212.5L467.234 225L454.734 242L442.234 260.5L418.734 299L413.734 308.5L408.734 319L399.234 339.5L383.234 382.5L377.734 401L373.734 420L370.234 434L367.734 448.5L364.234 472L363.617 505L363 538L364.234 557L365.5 573L368.697 597.209C368.898 598.728 369.316 600.211 369.939 601.612L375 613L377.5 619L380.5 624.5L383.5 630L387 635.5L391 640.5L396 646L401 650.5L406.5 655L416.441 661.326C417.146 661.775 417.885 662.167 418.651 662.501L427.919 666.53C428.639 666.843 429.381 667.102 430.139 667.307L442 670.5L454 673L467.5 674L480.5 674L502.192 672.114C503.063 672.038 503.925 671.891 504.772 671.675L525 666.5L546 658L557 652L567 646L581.5 635.5L595 624L606 613.5L616 602.5L623 594L629.5 586L642.5 569.5L666 534.5L677.5 517L688 498.5L698.5 480L708.5 461.5L726 427.5L734.5 410L742.5 392.5L751.964 372.152C752.321 371.385 752.616 370.591 752.847 369.778L760.348 343.381C761.215 340.327 760.519 337.041 758.486 334.602V334.602C755.927 331.531 751.736 330.365 747.959 331.672L746.16 332.295C743.01 333.385 740.434 335.7 739.015 338.716L733 351.5L724.5 369L697.5 423L658 494L648 510.5L636 528.5L624.5 544.5L612 560.5L598 576.5L583 591.5L568 605L552 617L540.5 623.5L528.5 629L517.5 633L508.5 635.5L499 637.5L481.449 639.347C480.485 639.449 479.514 639.463 478.547 639.388L467 638.5L455.463 637.169C454.49 637.057 453.529 636.855 452.592 636.567L442.266 633.389C441.423 633.13 440.604 632.802 439.816 632.408L430.99 627.995C429.67 627.335 428.447 626.495 427.357 625.5L418.537 617.447C417.847 616.817 417.213 616.127 416.644 615.387L412.5 610L408.66 603.599C408.221 602.868 407.841 602.102 407.524 601.31L402 587.5L397.5 571.5L394.5 553L393 534.5L393.5 496.5L395.5 475.5L398.5 455L403 434.5L408 414L412 401L416.5 388L421 375.5L426 363L436.5 338.5L448.5 314.5L461.5 291.5L475.5 269L491.5 246.5L508.234 225L525.5 205.5L544.5 187L564.5 170L584.223 154.503C585.072 153.836 585.987 153.257 586.953 152.774L602.5 145L610 141L617.5 137.5L633 132L648.297 127.828C649.098 127.61 649.915 127.454 650.74 127.362L663 126L673.622 126C674.87 126 676.113 126.146 677.327 126.435L680.375 127.161C684.01 128.026 687.227 130.136 689.469 133.126L690.375 134.333C691.451 135.767 692.278 137.373 692.821 139.082L695.081 146.182C695.36 147.059 695.563 147.959 695.687 148.871L697 158.5L698.5 169.5L699 172L699.297 173.782C699.432 174.592 699.641 175.388 699.922 176.16L700.927 178.925C701.298 179.946 702.003 180.815 702.924 181.39V181.39C704.497 182.373 706.498 182.376 708.07 181.394V181.394C708.996 180.815 709.7 179.941 710.067 178.912L712 173.5L713.825 167.375C714.097 166.46 714.287 165.523 714.393 164.574L715.234 157L715.734 148.5L715.31 138.303C715.26 137.105 715.075 135.916 714.76 134.759L713.734 131L710.55 121.621Z"
                />
                <path
                        d="M753.267 335.045C753.404 327.948 758.31 321.836 765.209 320.167V320.167C775.037 317.789 784.5 325.236 784.5 335.347L784.5 375L782 452.5L782 537L782 622L783 641.5L784 651.5L786 661L787.928 666.785C788.14 667.421 788.246 667.739 788.365 668.052C788.476 668.342 788.595 668.629 788.722 668.912C788.859 669.218 789.009 669.517 789.309 670.117L790.162 671.824C790.473 672.445 790.628 672.756 790.797 673.06C790.953 673.341 791.117 673.617 791.29 673.889C791.477 674.181 791.676 674.466 792.075 675.035L794.5 678.5L795.575 679.843C796.19 680.612 796.722 681.444 797.162 682.325L797.574 683.149C797.857 683.714 798.063 684.314 798.187 684.933L798.257 685.284C798.417 686.085 798.397 686.911 798.199 687.704V687.704C798.067 688.232 797.858 688.737 797.578 689.204L797.08 690.033C796.695 690.675 796.232 691.268 795.703 691.797V691.797C794.908 692.592 793.973 693.234 792.946 693.691L790 695L789.449 695.175C787.801 695.698 786.976 695.96 786.135 696.131C785.355 696.289 784.565 696.389 783.77 696.429C782.913 696.473 782.049 696.425 780.322 696.328L777.502 696.169C776.389 696.106 775.833 696.075 775.282 696.006C774.772 695.941 774.264 695.852 773.763 695.739C773.221 695.616 772.687 695.456 771.62 695.136L768.699 694.26C767.145 693.794 766.369 693.561 765.624 693.253C764.934 692.967 764.265 692.634 763.621 692.255C762.927 691.846 762.273 691.367 760.965 690.408L759.307 689.192C758.452 688.565 758.024 688.251 757.62 687.911C757.245 687.596 756.884 687.264 756.54 686.916C756.168 686.54 755.821 686.139 755.126 685.338L754.714 684.862C753.16 683.069 752.383 682.173 751.753 681.185C751.17 680.271 750.681 679.3 750.294 678.288C749.876 677.193 749.619 676.035 749.104 673.719L748.985 673.181C748.805 672.373 748.715 671.968 748.646 671.56C748.583 671.183 748.532 670.802 748.496 670.421C748.457 670.009 748.439 669.595 748.403 668.768L748 659.5L748 648.5L748 597L748.5 544.5L751.5 430L752.5 374.616L753.267 335.045Z"
                />
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```